# How to toggle accordion based on tr selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a list of names in a table and when you click on the selected table row the accordion will be pop-out but the problem is when I click one name all the accordion will show...

I Just put class in each row.

```
<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dev-info" class="accordion-toggle devs">
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" class="devID" value="{{$dev->id}}">
        <strong>{{$dev->last_name}}</strong>
    </td>
    <td><strong>{{$dev->first_name}}</strong></td>
    <td> <strong>{{$dev->middle_name}}</strong></td>
    <td>    
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a href="{{url('profile-view',$dev->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block viewProfile"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user "></i><b>View Profile</b></a>
        </div>  
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="hiddentablerow">
        <div class="box-group  accordian-body collapse dev-info">
            <!-- we are adding the .panel class so bootstrap.js collapse plugin detects it -->
            <div class="panel box box-info">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <h4 class="box-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                            Additional Information
                        </a>
                    </h4>

                    <div>
                        <select class="star-rating">
                            @foreach($dev->child_user_rating as $rate)
                            <option value="$rate->rating">{{count($rate->parent_user_rating_desc) > 0 ? $rate->parent_user_rating_desc[0]->description : 'Not Set'}},</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>

                    </div>  

                    <input type="hidden" class="devID" value="{{$dev->id}}">
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <strong><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope margin-r-5"></i> Email Address</strong>

                        <p class="text-muted">{{$dev->email}}</p>

                        <hr>

                        <strong><i class="fa fa-map-marker margin-r-5"></i> Location</strong>
                        <p class="text-muted">{{count($dev->child_user_location) > 0 ? $dev->child_user_location[0]->street : 'Not Set'}},{{count($dev->child_user_location) > 0 ? $dev->child_user_location[0]->brgy : 'Not Set'}},{{count($dev->child_user_location) > 0 ? $dev->child_user_location[0]->city : 'Not Set'}},{{count($dev->child_user_location) > 0 ? $dev->child_user_location[0]->province : 'Not Set'}},{{count($dev->child_user_location) > 0 ? $dev->child_user_location[0]->country : 'Not Set'}}</p>                                                    

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel box box-danger">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <h4 class="box-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                        Skills
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="box-body">

                    <strong><i class="fa fa-pencil margin-r-5"></i> Skills</strong>

                    <p>
                        @foreach($dev->child_user_specilization as $skill)
                        <span class="label label-success">{{$skill->sklill_desc->description}}</span>
                        @endforeach
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel box box-success">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <h4 class="box-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                            Achievements
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="box-body">

                        <strong><i class="fa fa-file-text-o margin-r-5"></i> Achievements</strong>

                        <p>
                            @foreach($dev->child_user_achievement as $achievement)
                            <span class="label label-success">{{$achievement->name}}</span>
                            @endforeach
                        </p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Should I use JQuery to filter the data? and if I use JQuery how to do it? since the pure html has the class to toggle the accordion.

Comment: I don't recognize the `@foreach` or `{{$achievement->name}}` syntax. This definitely isn't pure HTML. You'll have to specify what template engine / platform your using.

Comment: Ahh.. don't mind that.. that's laravel platform to show data from database...

Comment: Please specify which framework you are using or add tags to your question.

Comment: @solomon I'm using Laravel...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `data-target=".dev-info"` will select all elements with class `dev-info`

You may want to assign an id to your collapse element, for example, the `$dev->id` which I guess it is unique.

So instead of

```
<div class="box-group  accordian-body collapse dev-info">
```

Use

```
<div id="dev-info-{{$dev->id}}" class="box-group  accordian-body collapse dev-info">
```

and instead of

```
<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dev-info" class="accordion-toggle devs">
```

Use

```
<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dev-info-{{$dev->id}}" class="accordion-toggle devs">
```

I don't have your code, so I made this exmaple

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <body>
  
  <table border="1" cellpadding="5" width="50%">
<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#data1" class="accordion-toggle">
 <td>Data 1</td>
 <td>COL 2</td>
 <td>COL 3</td>
 <td>COL 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="4">
  <div id="data1" class="box-group  accordian-body collapse dev-info">Additional Information for Data 1</div>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#data2" class="accordion-toggle">
 <td>Data 2</td>
 <td>COL 2</td>
 <td>COL 3</td>
 <td>COL 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="4">
  <div id="data2" class="box-group  accordian-body collapse dev-info">Additional Information for Data 2</div>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it guys...

I just add this in Jquery..

```
$('tr.devs').click(function(){
   $(this).nextUntil('tr.devs').css('display', function(i,v){
        return this.style.display === 'table-row' ? 'none' : 'table-row';
    });
});
```